# Apache Ignite - Near Cache consistency

Tags: java, ignite

I am evaluating Apache Ignite to check if it fits our company's need. So far so good. Now I am trying to understand how the near cache feature works in terms of consistency.

We currently have several micro-services with one Ignite configured in client mode in each. All these instances are connected to several Ignite servers in a cluster. For some use cases (reads>>>writes) it seems reasonable to use a near cache in front of the cache servers. I have checked and it seems to automatically invalidate "stale data" in all instances in case of the write, which is good.

My question: is there any documentation besides [this one](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/near-caches) that explains how it works? In particular, I would like to understand if any subsequent read requests (after the write one) to any other instances will get the updated data (no eventual consistency).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With [`FULL_SYNC` mode](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/primary-and-backup-copies#section-synchronous-and-asynchronous-backups) all copies are always consistent, no eventual consistency. Near cache functions as a sort of additional backup copy.

I don't think there is a design document on how it works though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stanislav.
That means near caches use the same synchronization mechanism as the primary/backups. So i guess it does not make sense to use PRIMARY_SYNC with near cache, right?